# htaccess redirect if url contains specific string

Tags: .htaccess

We've installed a new shop software and I've set up redirects for all of the old pages, but there's one that I just can't get to work. If the url includes

cp_tpl=productlist.html

then I want to redirect to the main website. So for example the old url could be

http://www.gocellular.ca/index.php?cp_tpl=productlist.html&cp_cat=803&cp_sid=1xxxxxx

and I want to redirect to

www.gocellular.ca

The 'cp_tpl=productlist.html' can be anywhere in the url - basically I just want to check if the string 'cp_tpl=productlist.html' is included anywhere in the url and then redirect. I've tried about 100 different .htaccess re-writes but just can't get this to work! I'd be very grateful for any ideas.... THANK YOU!

Comment: List some of the RewriteRules you've tried.

Comment: Is RewriteRule cp_tpl=productlist\.html http: //www.gocellular.ca/ [R,L] not working?  (Without the space after http: of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to catch that string in the query string as you have shown it there you have to use a RewriteCond, as the regular expression doesn't get checked against the query string in a redirect rule.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cp_tpl=productlist.html
RewriteRule .* / [R,L]
```

The above will keep the query string intact.  If yow want to remove the query string, just add a ? after /, i.e.:

```
RewriteRule .* /? [R,L]
```

Comment: I have implemented this but it didn't worked for me. If my url contains  word 'forum' then it should be redirects to 83answers.com. I wrote following in my htaccess
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} forum
RewriteRule .* 83answers.com [R,L]
But it didn't work, please help me to sort this out

Comment: This question is specifically about the query string. Something along the lines of `RewriteRule forum 83answers.com [R,L]` should cover the rest of the URL.