# htaccess Redirect if query string variable present

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, append

I need to add `style=2` to all urls within a directory ONLY if the url does NOT already contain `style=2`.

Within the directory root, I have an .htaccess with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?style=|&style=)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1&style=2? [R=301,QSA]
```

I know it's wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: So basically the opposite of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120763/htaccess-redirect-if-url-contains-specific-string?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to this to make it work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)style=2(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?style=2 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is properly tested code on all browsers so check your other .htaccess/code if that is causing too many redirects.

Comment: i want to check if user enters no paramters in url

Comment: You can use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`

Comment: i want to do something like
if in url only domain i.e. http://example.com/
then i have to redirect like http://example.com/1/1

Comment: and if in url there is already parameters like http://example.com/1/2 
then nothing redirect

Comment: Not fair to start Q&A trail via comments on someone's question. Create a new question and I will try to answer it.

Comment: here is my question
i have banned in this account to ask question so please give answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808027/i-need-to-add-paramters-in-a-url-if-user-only-enters-the-domain-name-using-htacc

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?style=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?style=2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: i want to check any keyword in URI

Comment: please make another question and explain a little more what you want to do and what you tried so that we can help you. Not here.