# mod_rewrite and conditions - "if" on a query string

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm new with but have been studying .htaccess mod_rewrite for the last few days and I'm just finally wrapping my head around it. I was wondering if it was possible to have a simple check to see if a query string equals something specific..  for example:

```
#First check
RewriteCond $1 !^(img|font|js|css|scripts) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

#if $2 is upgrade, use this ReWrite
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} $2=upgrade
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=upgrade&tool=$2 [QSA,L]

#If not found... Use this regular ReWrite
RewriteCond $1 !^(img|font|js|css|scripts) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&user=$2 [QSA,L]
```

I've searched for conditions and such but nothing really turned up a "yes or no" on the possibility of writing such a statement although I've found similar aspects (found [on stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066142/htaccess-redirect-if-query-string-variable-present) )  like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)user=upgrade(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&user=upgrade&tool=$2 [L]
```

Couldn't get it to work.