# i need to add paramters in a url if user only enters the domain name using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

i had the domain name   and i have to redirect the url if in url there is nothing passed  like  "**http://example.com**"
then i have to redirect like here
**http://www.example.com/abc/1/2/3**
so if url there is nothing after domain excluding "/" then i have to redirect with my  specified url

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)
RewriteRule ^ mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /abc/1/2/3 [R=302,L]
```

It should only redirect `example.com` to `example.com/abc/1/2/3`

Comment: Great Dude its working for me
i dont have 15+ so i cant vote ++ vote up